# Why do some cached responses in Chrome appear as not-cached in devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, I have a page that loads an IFRAME from `/test` on the same origin, and the server waits 500ms before returning the response to that request.  By looking at devtools I can see that the response is being returned in less than 500ms:

[image: fast and small - cached?]

I can also inspect my network traffic and verify that no network request is leaving the browser.  Why isn't this request shown like this:

[image: definitively from cache]

Is there only a certain subset of cached resources that show up as "from disk cache" or "from memory cache" in devtools?

(Chrome 62)